# How to get just a single image from a video?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, video

I've been going through many codes on it but I've not found a working solution yet. I'm using Xcode 5.1.1 and Iphone Retina 4inch.I want to get a single image from a video by clicking on it. After that, I'll edit the image and apply the effects to entire video.  Thank you.

UPDATE:
I've found this code for the same purpose. It's not working on the simulator either. Can somebody tell me what's the problem?

```
 -(UIImage *)generateThumbImage : (NSString *)filepath
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];

AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
CMTime time = [asset duration];
time.value = 0;
CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);  // CGImageRef won't be released by ARC

return thumbnail;
```

}

Comment: Just saying it is not working is not that helpful. Can you explain in more detail where you have placed this code, how you are calling it ( connection in IB) and what if any errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

This code will generating an image from a particular time in the loaded video and convert the image from a CGImage to UIImage.

*The code is commented to explain its parts.*

```
- (UIImage*)loadImage {

    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:vidURL options:nil];

    AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset]; // Create object of Video. 

    NSError *err = NULL;

    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 60); // Select time of 1/60ths of a second. 

    CGImageRef imgRef = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err]; // Get Image on that time frame. 

    NSLog(@"err==%@, imageRef==%@", err, imgRef); // if something is not as expected then u can log error. 

    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef]; // Convert Image from CGImage to UIImage so you can display it easily in a image view. 

}
```

Comment: can please provide an explanation of what to expect from this code and any other details to help people understand it and use it.

Comment: Code is straight forward. Generating image on a particular time of the video and converting image CGImage to UIImage.

Comment: That may be the case. But your answers should include these details. Normally answers that just have code snippets are not as helpful to people who are not familiar with the code to know if it is what they are looking for because it lacks any description that will help them know if it is worth exploring. Can you edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried AVFoundation framework?

That's what it's for. The documentation is on the Apple site:

> AV Foundation framework provides essential services for working with
>   time-based audiovisual media on iOS and OS X. Through a modern
>   Objective-C interface, you can easily play, capture, edit, or encode
>   media formats such as QuickTime movies and MPEG-4 files.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. Can you please see the update and tell me what's wrong?